# Adding a document to a document (subdocs) does not work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Unfortunately, but the subdocument in mongoose does not work and I do not really know why:

```
...
mongoose.connect('mongodb://zzz@xxx.ccc.com:59676/zxcv');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
 
var entrySchema = Schema({
    title: String,
    img: String,
    info: String,
    link: String
}, {collection: 'xxx'});
 
var userDataSchema = Schema({
  name: String,
  password: { type: String, select: false},
  birth: Number,
  followers: [{ "name": String}],
  entry: [entrySchema]
}, {collection: 'yyy'});
 
var UserData = mongoose.model('UserData', userDataSchema);
var entry = mongoose.model('entry', entrySchema);
 
app.get('/:user', function(req, res) {
    UserData.findOne( {'name': req.params.user}, function(err, user) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(user);
    });
});
```

This code returns data from the userDataSchema scheme and empty entry: []. 
I can query userDataSchema and entrySchema separately and return correct data, but it does not work together. Where do I make a mistake? 
By default, I would like to dynamically add all collections (name in followers) to my schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-define your schemas to use **[`populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)** as:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema; 

var entrySchema = Schema({
    title: String,
    img: String,
    info: String,
    link: String
}, {collection: 'xxx'});

var userDataSchema = Schema({
    name: String,
    password: { type: String, select: false },
    birth: Number,
    followers: [{ "name": String}],
    entry: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'entry' }]
}, {collection: 'yyy'});


var UserData = mongoose.model('UserData', userDataSchema);
var entry = mongoose.model('entry', entrySchema);

app.get('/:user', function(req, res) {
    UserData.findOne({'name': req.params.user})
        .populate('entry')
        .exec(function(err, user) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json(user);
        });
});
```

This works given that you have actually saved the references to the `entry` model as `_id`s in the `userData` collection.

For in-depth explanation of how the above works, consult the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

Comment: I would like to add the whole schema to this schema (rigidly), not just the ID

Comment: Why he would redefine his schema ? what if he wants to use subdocuments instead of references ?

Comment: @YouneL It's better to redfine the schema because the OP is referencing another collection `xxx` and just store references to the collection rather than creating redundancy by adding the same data from the collection as subdocuments.

Comment: I see now +1, but also he could remove collection name `{collection: 'xxx'}` and it should work too

Comment: @YouneL xxx refers to another collection, if I delete it, will it be connected to it?

Comment: No it's necessary to use references as @chridam said

Answer (score 1):

```
var entrySchema = new Schema({
                  ^^^
    title: String,
    img: String,
    info: String,
    link: String
});
```

**Edit:** when you declared `entrySchema` with `{collection: 'xxx'}` you force mongoose to create a separete collection with name of `xxx`, that's why you should reference the `entrySchema` inside `userDataSchema` as described by chridam's answer, or remove collection option: `{collection: 'xxx'}`

Comment: unfortunately, but it does not change anything

Comment: Are you sure that the user id passed on parameter has a non empty entry ?

Comment: This code return me: {
    "followers": [
        {
            "name": "123"
        }
    ],
    "entry": [],
    "_id": "123123123123",
    "name": "qwe",
    "birth": 1231323
}